# Триггер на обновление поля в таблице

Tags: sql, postgresql, триггер, plpgsql

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: у меня в таблице Сотрудник есть ИНН, но у некоторых сотрудников может не быть ИНН, поэтому не могу поставить ограничение на уникальность. 
Создал два триггера на добавление и на обновление поля ИНН.
С триггером на добавление вообще проблем не было, а вот на обновление не могу понять как его написать.
Допустим есть два сотрудника у которых есть ИНН, и вот одному из них по религиозным причинам нужно убрать ИНН, но мой триггер то может сделать NULL, то выдает не понятную ошибку,а нужно сделать когда идет обновление то:

1. проверять нет ли у кого-то из других сотрудников таких же ИНН.Е сли значение ИНН пришло не NULL.
2. если пришло значение ИНН NULL, то изменить на NULL.
3. если обновляется там в таблице, например Имя, а ИНН тот же - то не менять его.

Вот триггер на добавления:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION maindb.InsertIdentificationCode() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
DECLARE 
tempIdentification CHAR(10);
BEGIN

SELECT IdentificationCode INTO tempIdentification
FROM maindb.Employees
WHERE IdentificationCode = NEW.IdentificationCode;

IF (tempIdentification IS NOT NULL) THEN
RAISE EXCEPTION 'Сотрудник с таким ИНН уже существует';
RETURN OLD;
ELSE
RETURN NEW; 
END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER InsertIdentification
BEFORE INSERT ON maindb.Employees FOR EACH ROW 
EXECUTE PROCEDURE maindb.InsertIdentificationCode();
```

а вот триггер на обновление

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION maindb.UpdateIdentificationCode() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
DECLARE 
tempIdentification CHAR(10);
BEGIN

SELECT IdentificationCode INTO tempIdentification
FROM maindb.Employees
WHERE IdentificationCode = NEW.IdentificationCode AND ID = NEW.ID;


IF (tempIdentification IS NULL) THEN
RETURN NEW;
ELSE
RAISE EXCEPTION 'Ошибка';
RETURN OLD;
END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER UpdateIdentification
BEFORE UPDATE ON maindb.Employees FOR EACH ROW 
EXECUTE PROCEDURE maindb.UpdateIdentificationCode();
```

Comment: "_но у некоторых сотрудников может не быть ИНН по этому не могу поставить ограничение на уникальность_". Вообще говоря, очень даже можете. индексы не учитывают NULL ключи. Вы можете создать обычный уникальный индекс по полю ИНН и он будет учитывать уникальность только заполненных полей, а NULL значений можно вставить сколько угодно

Comment: То есть если я создам уникальный индек по полю ИНН, надобность в триггерах отпадёт? Я верно понял?

Comment: @Mike сработало, спасибо огромное), а то уже день вожусь с этими триггерами(